# Product page (Does not show a category when displayed on homepage)

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

When i list my products on front page (from Default Category (Father of all other categories anchor is set YES)), when click in any product, the product page (product view) doesn't show the category of this product.

Category of product doesn't show in Breadcumb and URL
My product is acessible via direct link, like this:
mystore.com/product-name, when i see on list of category page, the url is mystore.com/category/product-name, i want force always show the category of this product.

Note: Magento 1.9.2.4

What i need do?

Thanks!

Comment: whats your magento version 1 or 2

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Sorry, magento 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php` you will find `getBreadcrumbPath()` **function** in which **they look for** the `Mage::registry('current_category')`

```
public function getBreadcrumbPath()
    {
        if (!$this->_categoryPath) {

            $path = array();
            if ($category = $this->getCategory()) {
                $pathInStore = $category->getPathInStore();
                $pathIds = array_reverse(explode(',', $pathInStore));

                $categories = $category->getParentCategories();

                // add category path breadcrumb
                foreach ($pathIds as $categoryId) {
                    if (isset($categories[$categoryId]) && $categories[$categoryId]->getName()) {
                        $path['category'.$categoryId] = array(
                            'label' => $categories[$categoryId]->getName(),
                            'link' => $this->_isCategoryLink($categoryId) ? $categories[$categoryId]->getUrl() : ''
                        );
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($this->getProduct()) {
                $path['product'] = array('label'=>$this->getProduct()->getName());
            }

            $this->_categoryPath = $path;
        }
        return $this->_categoryPath;
    }
```

in `if` condition

```
public function getCategory()
{
    return Mage::registry('current_category');
}
```

As you are going from the home page that time `Mage::registry('current_category')` is not set thats why category path is not getting display.

if your url is `mystore.com/category/product-name` then it will display breadcrumb

As you mentioned  **I want force always show the category of this product.**

Solution :

You can set `current_category` before product page loads **but Product can be from multiple categories**.

OR

create template file create the product list and **set anchor by full product url**.

OR

Edit in core file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php` (**not good practice and its abstract file**)

Answer (score 0):

Login adminPanel

GOto

`system->configuration->catalog->catalog->Search Engine Optimizations`

and set `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` to `yes`

Then clear cache and do reindex and check

Comment: It is already configured that way. The product displayed on the homepage when I click the URL on it is mystore.com/product-name, and yes i cleaned all caches..

Comment: @user1533106 provide code that you are using for product collection

Comment: {{block type='catalog/product_list' category_id='2' grid_column_count='2' hide_toolbar='1' template='catalog/product/list.phtml'}} category_id=2 is "Default Category"

Comment: I want block direct acess like this: mystore.com/product-name, and force this: mystore.com/category/product-name

Comment: i guess i found the problem, on menu Catalog - Manage URL Rewrites, this have rules to rewrite like: category/product-name, and just product-name, need configure category anchor or anything like this? i want display all products on home page from default category...